# How to get Item from POJO in listview onClick()?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a POJO, which describes some model (Item?) and some custom Adapter.

I am setting my adapter for ListView and then, in onItemClick() I want to get value of one of variables which I had added Into the Item.

**How I can reach this?**

In my code I am doing something like:

```
private List<SomeItem> items = new ArrayList();
items.add(new SomeItem(firstValueString, secondValueBitmap, thirdValueString));
SomeAdapter adapter = new SomeAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(
...
@Override
public void onItemClick(){
//How to reach for example firstValueString value of currently clicked item??
}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
            + id);
        SomeItem item = items.get(position); // specific item
      }
    });
```

Comment: exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Android SDK documentation:

> Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

If you implement your adapter completely then you can get item like bellow:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Item item = (Item)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
});
```